# Setting the "config.fxp-asset.installer-paths" option in composer

Tags: php, configuration, composer-php

When I run a `composer update` I get the following warning before it proceeds with the update.

```
The "extra.asset-installer-paths" option is deprecated, use the "config.fxp-asset.installer-paths" option
```

Where/how can I change these settings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace the `extra.asset-installer-paths` section with:

```
    "config": {
        "fxp-asset": {
            "installer-paths": {
                "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
                "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
            }
        },
    }
```

See [Define a custom directory for the assets installation](https://github.com/fxpio/composer-asset-plugin/blob/HEAD/Resources/doc/index.md#define-a-custom-directory-for-the-assets-installation)